# How do I find the network interface ID associated with an Azure VM

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I can find the VM by using

```
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "MyResource" -Name "MyVM"
```

But how can I find the network interface associated with this VM?

Comment: this was answered thousand times here already

Comment: can you post a link to the most popular one, so others may benefit as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your VM in a variable $vm (as shown below)

```
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "MyResource" -Name "MyVM"
```

You can get the NIC by finding the interface that matches the ID from your VM

```
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface 
       | Where {$_.Id -eq $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Shiroy your post helped me out today.  I just wanted to post the new versions of the commands in case anyone came across this post needing the same information that I did.

```
$vm = Get-AzVm -ResourceGroupName "YourResourceGroup" -Name "YourVM"

$nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where {$_.Id -eq $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, what's the point of this answer? It's basically a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/53739801/7264739

Comment: The point of the answer was to show the actual commands that would function, in 2023.  I found this post but his commands though accurate no longer function against Azure especially if you have already moved on to Powershell 7 as your daily shell instead of Powershell 5.